# preventing a rails app from running a validation on a particular action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to do the following validation on my rails app. But I dont want  to do the below validation on the `create` action.

```
validates :bed_room, :bath_room, :listing_name, :summary, :building_name, presence: true, unless: "status.draft?"
```

so how can I prevent it from doing that on `create` action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using the `on` option:

```
validates :attribute, presence: true, on: :update
```

Plain as day in the [Rails Validation Docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#common-validation-options)

Comment: Isnt it running the validation on create? I dont want the validation on create

Comment: Is there an except? or something like so?

Comment: There are only two settings for the `on` option, `:create` or `:update`. Why isn't `on: :update` good enough?

Comment: I dont want to force users on update aswell as am trying to make some kind of draft functionality

Comment: You don't want to run the validation on `create` or `update`? You should probably clarify your question then.

Comment: but before publishing they need to provide those fields..Thats why I want to put validation with conditions

Comment: You would still apply the validation, but only if the record is in a "live" state (not a "draft"). You would do this using the code you've already implemented: `unless: "..."`

Comment: yes you are right..forget about that for a second..Thanks